# server side framework

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, web

I'm building a large web application with a lot of JavaScript and jQuery (ajax is also inside). There will be a database too with several tables and I use mySQL to manage it.

My question is which server side framework should I use. Right now I consider Rails and Node.js with libraries.

I am aware that there are couple of similar questions on stackoverflow but all of them are quite old. I assume that over a year or two things may change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a large application with a lot of javaScript, I am assuming that you have a good understanding of the language. My advise is to stick to javaScript.There are a lot of good javaScript frameworks that are pretty good and can handle large application. Some of the Frameworks you can use are AngularJS, EmberJS and BackboneJS(the most popular). And with the [MEAN stack](http://mean.io/)(Mongo, Express, Angular & Node), which is a Fullstack javaScript framework, it will accelerate your workflow.

Answer (score 1):

It really is up to you what language or framework you want to use. You can use rails if you want to delve into ruby or if you like JS everywhere use node. If you want to stick with PHP you could use cakePHP. A lot of the frameworks are similar in that they follow MVC design. All your tables for models, views, and controllers would follow similar conventions in each framework I'm guessing. If you are already good with a language I would just stick with that then branch out if you are pressed for time. You can't really use PHP code with Rails or Node or at least it's uncommon.

Comment: I changed that (in my question). What I meant is that at this moment i wrote a number of PHP scripts but I'm aware that I'll have to rewrite them after switching to Rails or Node.

Comment: Sounds good, well in my opinion there is no "best" framework to use. You will just have to try them out for a bit and see which one you like best and which one works for you best. I personally enjoy cakePHP. Choose your weapon and choice and drive forward friend.

Comment: I believe you should use Node.js this case, since you are familiar with javascript.